# How to set the RowHeaderTemplate for a DataGrid programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, datagridrowheader

I have a WPF `DataGrid` written in XAML that I'm converting to C# (don't ask).

It looks something like this (some properties omitted for brevity):

```
var Card = new DataGrid() {
    Background          = Brushes.LightYellow,
    BorderBrush         = Brushes.DimGray,
    ColumnWidth         = new DataGridLength(100),
    Columns             = {
        new DataGridTextColumn() {
            Binding     = new Binding("In"),
            Header      = "In"
        },
        new DataGridTextColumn() {
            Binding     = new Binding("Out"),
            Header      = "Out"
        },
        new DataGridTextColumn() {
            Binding     = new Binding("Hours"),
            Header      = "Hours"
        }
    },
    RowHeaderTemplate   = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataGridRowHeader)) {
        VisualTree      =  Days
    },
    RowHeaderWidth      = 115,
    RowHeight           = 50
};
```

`Days` is setup like so:

```
var Days = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
Days.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Day"));
Days.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Lime);
```

When run, the `DataGrid`'s `RowHeader` is blank (and `LightYellow`, not `Lime`).

I've tried `Card.RowHeaderTemplate.VisualTree = Days;` also, to no avail.

Where am I going wrong? How can I set the `RowHeaderTemplate` programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates should be created using loading from XAML. Using element factories is obsolete and no longer supported (it may work in some cases, but won't work in other).

For example, [Caliburn.Micro creates default data templates](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/e82bc5a641485033dd4b94ea7b71cb115636e30c/src/Caliburn.Micro.Platform/ConventionManager.cs#L62) like this:

```
    public static DataTemplate DefaultHeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)
#if SILVERLIGHT || WinRT
    XamlReader.Load(
#else
    XamlReader.Parse(
#endif
       "<DataTemplate " +
       "    xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>" +
       "    <TextBlock Text=\"{Binding DisplayName, Mode=TwoWay}\" />" +
       "</DataTemplate>"
    );
```

Another link you may find useful: [Creating WPF Data Templates in Code
The Right Way](http://www.ikriv.com/dev/wpf/DataTemplateCreation/). It includes a sample of creating XAML string using XML and XAML classes, with references to assemblies and stuff.

Comment: I just tried this, changing `DisplayName` to `Day`. It has the same effect. No text and the background remains the same.

Comment: @DannyBeckett You'll need to include a working XAML sample and equivalent C# code, which doesn't work, in the question.

Comment: I had `<DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Item.Day}"/></DataTemplate>` and I tried your code, and then `var Days = (DataTemplate) XamlReader.Parse("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Item.Day}\"/></DataTemplate>");` Currently I'm getting a *Prefix 'x' does not map to a namespace* Exception.

Comment: Wahey, looks like it's working. I took this from the link you shared: `var context = new ParserContext(); context.XamlTypeMapper = new XamlTypeMapper(new string[0]); context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"); context.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");` and added the `, context` parameter to `Parse()`. Thanks for your help!